# Обобщающее слово перед "как... так и"

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос: если перед неповторяющимся союзом "как... так и", соединяющем однородные члены предложения, стоит обобщающее слово, надо ли перед союзом "как" ставить запятую?

Пример: " У нас работают все рабочие, как хорошие, так и плохие".

И приведите, пожалуйста, соответствующее правило русского языка.

Answer (score 7):

После обобщаюшего слова перед однородными членами ставится двоеточие. Наличие/отсутствие двоеточия никак не зависит от того, какими союзами соединяются однородные члены. А вот Ваша первая запятая не нужна, так как запятая ставится между однородными членами, а не перед ними. *У нас работают разные рабочие: как хорошие, так и плохие.*

Я заменила также обобщающее слово, мне оно по смыслу кажется более подходящим.

Comment: "В основе деятельности всех магазинов XXXYYY, как собственных, так и
франчайзинговых, лежит стратегия, ориентированная
на удовлетворение потребностей покупателей", - вот оригинальная фраза. Не думаю, что тут нужно двоеточие :)

Comment: Так всю фразу и надо приводить. Вы ее усекли, исказили - зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Сравните два предложения:
Прошлое для меня  как бы окрашено в разные цвета: синий, белый и коричневый.  (1)
На ней уже было другое платье, очень простое и очень ловкое. (2)
Предложение (1) – это предложение с обобщающим словом, отнесенным к  однородному ряду определений. Интонация: двоеточие соответствует   увеличенной паузе, предупреждающей о последующем перечислении, далее однородный ряд с перечислительной интонацией.  Запятая вместо двоеточия в таком предложении явно неуместна.
В предложении  (2) слово «другое» поясняется  однородными определениями, но они соединены союзом И составляют  единое целое. Интонация: предложение состоит из двух частей (фраз), при этом однородные определения входят в одну фразу. 
Попробуем изменить предложение:
На ней уже было другое платье – и очень простое,  и очень ловкое. Теперь  мы уже имеем  классический однородный ряд после обобщающего слова и соответствующую интонацию, как и в предложении (1).
Вывод
Можно обособить запятой два пояснительных определения, если они  связаны союзом И. Если же это однородный ряд с собственной интонацией перечисления, то нужны «более серьезные» знаки – двоеточие или тире. Только в этом случае между словами будут выражены смысловые пояснительные связи.
В приведенном примере именно такая ситуация:  У нас работают разные рабочие: как хорошие, так и плохие. 
Двоеточие ставится, если для вас по смыслу важнее однородный ряд. Возможно применение тире, если вы хотите логически подчеркнуть значимость слова «разные»
При решении  использовалась методика «Интонационное решение пунктуационных задач», позволяющая выразить следующие связи: смысловое значение – обобщенная интонация – соответствующий знак препинания.

Answer (score 1):

Для иллюстрации вопроса Вы привели неравнозначные конструкции.
"У нас работают все рабочие : как хорошие, так и плохие."-предложение можно охарактеризовать как простое с обобщающим словом и однородными членами и поставить двоеточие,а можно - как предложение с пояснением и поставить запятую: " У нас работают все рабочие, как хорошие, так и плохие".

В основе деятельности всех магазинов XXXYYY, как собственных, так и франчайзинговых, лежит стратегия, ориентированная на удовлетворение потребностей покупателей" - явно предложение с пояснением, нужны запятые с двух сторон.Возможно выделить с двух сторон тире - как попутное уточняющее замечание:
"В основе деятельности всех магазинов XXXYYY - как собственных, так и франчайзинговых -  лежит стратегия, ориентированная на удовлетворение потребностей покупателей".